# what replaces –-bwlimit= if it is depricated

Tags: rsync

`rsync -rlPWDvhz /source/dir –-bwlimit=75 /destination/dir` and

`rsync -rlPWDvhz –-bwlimit=75 /source/dir /destination/dir`

generates:

> rsync: link_stat  /source/dir –-bwlimit=75 failed: No such file or directory (2)

But this executes flawlessly:

`rsync -rlPWDvhz /source/dir /destination/dir`

The only difference between commands is `–-bwlimit`, what could cause the error? Is this error caused because `–-bwlimit` is being deprecated?

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
–-bwlimit=
```

with

```
--bwlimit=
```

You used one wrong dash.

Comment: Thank You Cyrus - copy and paste from terminal got me.